Как обощённые классы использовать в коллекции?
У класса есть такие зависимости.
private readonly IDataReceiver<A> _receiverA;
private readonly IDataReceiver<B> _receiverB;

Разные типы / разные базы данных
Хотелось бы их поместить в коллекцию, чтобы конструктор класса был с меньшим количеством параметров, но в таком случае что то совсем страшное выходит что вообще непонятно становится что классу нужно) типа такого:
private readonly Dictionary<Type, object> _receivers;

А использование:
var receiverA = new MockReceiver<A>();
var receiverB = new MockReceiver<B>();

var receivers = new Dictionary<Type, object>
{
    { typeof(A), receiverA },
    { typeof(B), receiverB }
};

Пробовал по разному, но всё равно всё вокруг objeсt получалось, какой может быть граммотный подход ?

Варианта 2: 1) общий родитель 2) (ко|контр)вариантный интерфейс. Смысл здесь в том что обобщения MyClass<A> и MyClass<B> это 2 разных класса, которые стоит воспринимать как MyClassA и MyClassB.

@aepot Спасибо!

Грамотный подход он всегда относительный. Потому что грамота в различный языках различна. Тема холиварная.
Много параметров в конструкторе говорит о том что у вас возможное нарушение SPR (single responsibility principle) и ваш "GOD class" делает чуть больше чем много
Но есть паттерны и я предполагаю что для вашего примера подойдёт паттерн Facade.
Прошу заменить что возможно нарушение принципа и возможно подойдёт паттерн Facade.
Существует также и другие возможности регистрации объектов в контейнере когда на выходе возможно получить IEnumerable<IDataReceiver> и просматривать коллекцию ресиверов. Но тут как говорится вкусовщина

Aziz Umarov - спасибо. Фасад если правильно помню, он что то наподобии отделения архитектуры от фреймворков. Чтобы архитектура не зависела от них. Но щас обновлю знания) Мне просто нужно по сути чтобы компонент отправлял то что смог обработать в одно место, то что не смог, в другое.

Фасад https://refactoring.guru/ru/design-patterns/facade

Сначала не понял, а потом как понял..., спасибо. Вот тут на примере подобные поля.https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1595893/%d0%9d%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%83%d1%88%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b2-solid-%d0%b8-%d0%b4%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%b5
