Нарушение принципов SOLID и другое
Задача:
В таблице RawLinks [ID,Link] скапливаюься необработанные (с мусором) ссылки на подобии этой 325230fkewf ru.stackoverflow.com/users/373567/ odwf3430. Необходимо определять их тип, нормализовать в соответствии с типоп, проверять по базе уже существующих ссылок, если нет, сохранить.
Cамо решение задачи не интересует, она решается и так и сяк.
Нужна помощь с выделением сущности, с принципами SOLID
Загвоздка в понимании как лучше:

Нужно использовать 1 какую то сущность сохраняя её состоянии по разным таблицам ?
Или может быть нужно иметь объекты под все ситуации, типа RawLink, DefinedLink, NotDefinedLinks и т.д.
Или может сущность и DTO
Или вообще всё как то иначе

Код 1 из 3 подобных микро компонентов
public class StackOverflowLink
{
    public string Link { get; set; }
}

public class TypedStackOverflowLink : StackOverflowLink
{
    public TypeStackOverflowLink Type { get; set; }
}

public class Definer(IDataSource<StackOverflowLink> dataSourceRawLink, IDataReceiver<TypedStackOverflowLink> dataReceiverDefinedLink, IDataReceiver<StackOverflowLink> dataReceiverNotDefinedLink)
{
    public async Task StartAsync()
    {
        while (true) 
        {
            try
            {
                await UnitWorkAsync();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(ex);
            }

            await Task.Delay(1000);
        }
    }

    // Открыт для интеграционного теста
    public async Task UnitWorkAsync() 
    {
        StackOverflowLink rawLink = await WaitGetRawLinkAsync();

        TypeStackOverflowLink typeStackOverflowLink = DefineType(rawLink);

        await WaitReceiveAsync(typeStackOverflowLink, rawLink);
    }

    private async Task<StackOverflowLink> WaitGetRawLinkAsync()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            try
            {
                StackOverflowLink? rawLink = await dataSourceRawLink.GetAsync();

                if (rawLink != null)
                {
                    return rawLink;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(ex);
            }

            await Task.Delay(1000);
        }
    }

    private async Task WaitReceiveAsync(TypeStackOverflowLink typeStackOverflowLink, StackOverflowLink rawLink) 
    {
        while (true)
        {
            try
            {
                switch (typeStackOverflowLink)
                {
                    case TypeStackOverflowLink.User:
                    case TypeStackOverflowLink.Question:
                        await dataReceiverDefinedLink.ReceiveAsync(new TypedStackOverflowLink()
                        {
                            Link = rawLink.Link,
                            Type = typeStackOverflowLink
                        });
                        break;
                    case TypeStackOverflowLink.Unknown:
                        await dataReceiverNotDefinedLink.ReceiveAsync(rawLink);
                        break;
                    case TypeStackOverflowLink.None:
                    default:
                        throw new ArgumentException($"Неожиданный тип enum typeStackOverflowLink = {typeStackOverflowLink}");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(ex);
            }
        }
    }

    private TypeStackOverflowLink DefineType(StackOverflowLink stackOverflowLink)
    {
        if (Regex.IsMatch(stackOverflowLink.Link, @"ru\.stackoverflow\.com/questions/\d+/"))
        {
            return TypeStackOverflowLink.Question;
        }
        else if (Regex.IsMatch(stackOverflowLink.Link, @"ru\.stackoverflow\.com/users/\d+/"))
        {
            return TypeStackOverflowLink.User;
        }
        else
        {
            return TypeStackOverflowLink.Unknown;
        }
    }
}

PS. Хотел написать вопрос касально проекта из связки независимо работающих 3х компонентов, но он через чур громоздкий для поста( и такое наверно даже никто не прочитает, поэтому попробую по чуть чуть.

Принципы ООП нарушить невозможно. Принципы ООП - это инкапсуляция, наследование и полиморфизм. Вы можете пользоваться принципами при разработке, а можете не пользоваться. Нарушать здесь даже теоретически нечего. Быть может вы имели в виду принципы SOLID, но я не буду гадать.


So - не ленитесь, давайте нормальные имена, а не сокращения. Что более понятней, SoLink, или StackOverflowLink? 2. Ваш SoLink бесполезен - это бесполезная обертка над строкой, смысл? 3. Наследование типа от ссылки - это как наследовать цветок от птицы, совершенно нелогичное действие. 4. Ваш "определитель" тоже как по мне бесполезен - вот какой смысл гонять бесконечный цикл, что-то ждать, если можно при получении просто запустить нужный метод? 5. Receive переводится как "получить", ну а вы сами пишете "компонент отдаёт приёмникам", можно-ли этот метод назвать "получением"?


Вы бы хоть задачу описали свою

@aepot да, извиняюсь, имел ввиду SOLID

@EvgeniyZ спасибо за комментарии. 1. Допустим если в каком то моменте будет уже такое длинное название StackOverflowNotDefinedLink - это будет норм ? или нужно искать более короткие понятные назавания ? 3. Понял, думал что нужно какое то имя дать что ожидается строка связанная со Stackoverflow. 4. Тут да, попытался реальный пример продемонстрировать на stackoverflow, в реальном проекте там всё оч сложно с определением типа. 5. Получатель имел ввиду


То, что вы привели - это не длинное название, в C# есть и куда длиннее названия (PlatformNotSupportedException например). Конечно если вы там поэму целую строчите и она не понятная все еще, то стоит получше подумать над неймингом, да и структурой в целом. 3. Тут дело не в имени, а в вашей архитектуре. Почему свойство типа лежит в отдельном классе, который еще и наследуется от основного класса? Почему не сделать просто class { Url, Type } Это ведь один объект, а не 2 разных. 5. Тогда вызвав метод "Получатель" - вы должны что-то получить, а вы сейчас наоборот, отправляете данные куда-то.


@EvgeniyZ получатель, получает)

Что первое приходит в голову, когда вы вызываете Данные.ПолучитьАсинхронно(...)? Я лично предполагаю, что вызвав данный метод, я получу то, что прошу, логично? Да, только вот на деле я отправляю что-то в эти самые "Данные". Как по мне, тут всеж что-то не то... Но, дело конечно ваше.

@EvgeniyZ по поводу бесполезная обертка над строкой - задам отдельным вопросом. А вот Наследование типа от ссылки - это как наследовать цветок от птицы, совершенно нелогичное действие.  Вы имели ввиду TypedStackOverflowLink : StackOverflowLink ? Т.е. это как бы не связанные объекты по сути ? StackOverflowLink не может быть родителем TypedStackOverflowLink ? Или я не правильно понял(

Изначально вопрос был про "Нарушение принципов ООП". Если отвечать именно на него, то я бы отметил ручную диспетчеризацию (умное слово ввернул!) в методе WaitReceiveAsync: switch по TypeStackOverflowLink. Тут напрашивается классический рефакторинг с созданием классов вместо перечисления. То есть метод DefineType должен возвращать не enum, а один из классов-потомков некоего базового класса. И, соответственно, вместо switch'а просто вызывается метод этого объекта. Это будет ООП. Нужно ли оно? Вопрос спорный.

@AlexanderPetrov Воот, подобный разбор я ожидал. Спасибо! Как то так ? Базовый класс для всех далее перечисленных, возможно абстрактный StackOverflowLink с одним свойством Link. затем получаю RawStackOverflowLink, после метода Defined, возвращаю DefinedStackOverflowLink или NotDefinedStackOverflowLink ? Я делал подобно, но меня смущало огромное количество однотипных классов(

Да, слепое следование принципам ООП часто приводит к раздуванию кода. Поэтому следует знать о разных вариантах проектирования и выбирать оптимальный для каждого конкретного случая.

@AlexanderPetrov а ещё смущает момент, в switch можно просто тапнуть и все типы enum раскроются, а в случае если какой то базовый класс возвращать, там придётся что то типа if is else if is делать ручками. Если тип является этим типом то это, а если этим, то это. Но с много типов объектов, хорошо читается.

Скорее всего вы имели в виду принцип "single responsibility" из SOLID. Но вообще тут скорее нужно исходить из того, как оптимально спроектировать БД под эту задачу. Если я правильно понимаю, если отсеять всю шелуху, у вас есть исходные сырые ссылки и почищенные, проверенные, типизированные чистые ссылки. Ну вот я бы и сделал две таблицы в БД, условно назовём:

RawLinks
TypedLinks

В первой таблице как сами сырые ссылки, так и необходимые данные для работы задачи по очистке ссылок. Фактически, это таблица задач.
Во второй таблице - результат чистки. С отсылкой к первой таблице - из чего это у нас такая ссылочка получилась, из какого мусора.
Зачем именно две таблицы. Просто чтобы задачи, которые работают с чистыми ссылками быстрее читали данные. Как вариант, вторая таблица может быть "витриной" или копией "очищенной" ссылки, лежащей в первой таблице. Тут нужно смотреть - кто у вас этими "очищенными" ссылками пользуется и насколько ему критична скорость чтения из БД, нужна ли вообще тут эта оптимизация с разбивкой на две таблицы.
С первой же таблицей всё понятно. Единая таблица из обработанных и ещё необработанных сырых ссылок нужна, чтобы у вас не было дублей, когда вы туда новую необработанную ссылку будете добавлять. Ну и нужен признак обработанности. И я бы ещё добавил поле "следующее время обработки", если ссылки могут быть проблемными и скачиваться/обрабатываться не всегда с первого раза. Для таких ссылок это время переносится в будущее обработчиком этих ссылок.
Ну вот как-то так. То есть по сути получается две таблицы с единственной ответственностью:

Обработка сырых ссылок
Хранение готовых ссылок

Как именно хранить готовые ссылки разных типов, в одной таблице, или делить на несколько - опять же зависит от того, сколько этих типов, сколько записей в таблице и т.д. Т.е. опять же смотрим с точки зрения оптимизации работы с БД. Если там миллиарды записей каждого вида, которые сервис должен непрерывно лопатить, то лучше разделить на несколько таблиц. А если записей немного и сервис не критичный по времени на чтение/фильтрацию этих записей, то можно и в одну таблицу свалить.
Не уверен, что сильно помог, но рассуждать можно примерно так.

CrazyElf - спасибо! Но сервисам же должно быть без разницы где и как хранятся данные.

@Xzizz Сферическим сервисам в вакууме - возможно. Но, повторюсь - смотря что за сервисы. Конечно, в теории нужно стремиться к максимальной абстрактности. Но если нам не хватает скорости и мы начинаем что-то оптимизировать, то неизбежно придётся смотреть на конкретику и оптимизировать именно её. Кроме того, многое зависит от того, на какие сущности вы разобьёте ваши объекты. Ссылка - это вроде бы и одна сущность. А сырые ссылки и очищенные ссылки - уже вроде как и две сущности. Если идти не от сущностей, а от процессов, то с точки зрения SOLID на верхнем уровне у вас один процесс - очистка.
